# Does a function really need to return promise for async-await to work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, async-await, es6-promise

My doubt is that ,can i write a normal function and do an await to call that function.
I'll explain it more clearly with an example
consider this function

```
let splitStringAndConvertToInt=(data)=>{
  let splitData=data.split("-")
  let bothValues={
    first:parseInt(splitData[0]),
    last:parseInt(splitData[1])
  }
  return bothValues
 }
```

Above is the function i am going to call,
below is main function

```
let allocateRoomAccordingToNeeds=async (request)=>{
  let mode=request.mode
  let totRooms=request.totalRooms
  let firstYearBtech=await splitStringAndConvertToInt(request.firstYearBtech)
  let secondYearBtech=await splitStringAndConvertToInt(request.secondYearBtech)
  let thirdYearBtech=await splitStringAndConvertToInt(request.thirdYearBtech)
  let fourthYearBtech=await splitStringAndConvertToInt(request.fourthYearBtech)
  let firstYearMtech=await splitStringAndConvertToInt(request.firstYearMtech)
  let secondYearMtech=await splitStringAndConvertToInt(request.secondYearMtech)
  let others=await splitStringAndConvertToInt(request.others)
  let tutors=await splitStringAndConvertToInt(request.tutors)
  let staff=await splitStringAndConvertToInt(request.staff)
  if (mode="Category" )
  {
   Room.updateMany({Room_number:{ $gte:firstYearBtech.first,$lte:firstYearBtech.last }}, {"$set":{"position": "1 year btech"}}, (err, writeResult) => {if(err){console.log("error in 1 btech"+err)} else{
     Room.updateMany({Room_number:{ $gte:secondYearBtech.first,$lte:secondYearBtech.last }}, {"$set":{"position": "2 year btech"}}, (err2, writeResult2) => {if(err2){console.log("error in 2 btech"+err2)} else{
       Room.updateMany({Room_number:{ $gte:thirdYearBtech.first,$lte:thirdYearBtech.last }}, {"$set":{"position": "3 year btech"}}, (err3, writeResult3) => {if(err3){console.log("error in 3 btech"+err3)} else{
         Room.updateMany({Room_number:{ $gte:fourthYearBtech.first,$lte:fourthYearBtech.last }}, {"$set":{"position": "4 year btech"}}, (err4, writeResult4) => {if(err4){console.log("error in 4 b tech"+err4)} else{
           Room.updateMany({Room_number:{ $gte:firstYearMtech.first,$lte:firstYearMtech.last }}, {"$set":{"position": "1 year mtech"}}, (err1m, writeResult1m) => {if(err1m){console.log("error in 1 mtech"+err1m)} else{
             Room.updateMany({Room_number:{ $gte:secondYearMtech.first,$lte:secondYearMtech.last }}, {"$set":{"position": "2 year mtech"}}, (err2m, writeResult2m) => {if(err2m){console.log("error in 2 mtech"+err2m)} else{
               Room.updateMany({Room_number:{ $gte:others.first,$lte:others.last }}, {"$set":{"position": "others"}}, (errO, writeResultO) =>{if(errO){console.log("error in others"+errO)} else{
                 Room.updateMany({Room_number:{ $gte:tutors.first,$lte:tutors.last }}, {"$set":{"position": "tutors"}}, (errT, writeResultT) => {if(errT){console.log("error in tutor"+errT)} else{
                   Room.updateMany({Room_number:{ $gte:staff.first,$lte:staff.last }}, {"$set":{"position": "staff"}}, (errS, writeResultS) => {
                      if(errS){
                         console.log("error in staff"+errS)
                      }
                      else{
                        console.log("Success allocation of Room")
                        res.send("Succes allocation of room")
                   }})
                 }})
               }})
             }})
           }})
         }})
       }})
     }})
   }});
  }
  else if(mode="Custom" ){
   Room.updateMany({"$set":{"position": "Custom"}}, (error, resultUp) => {
     if(error){
       console.log("error in Custom mode"+error)}
     else{
       console.log("successful upload of custom mode")
     }})
  }
}
```

and below is root code of all these

```
   router.post('/authentication/changeallocationmode', function(req, res, next){
     //add code to assign same years to the given list if they are somewhere else and also add code to warn that given limit is not enough
       let vacate=req.body.vacate
       if(vacate==true){
         Room.updateMany({$set:{Roommates:["Null","Null","Null"],Occupied:false,Allocated:false}})
         .then(()=>{allocateRoomAccordingToNeeds(req.body)})
       }
       else {allocateRoomAccordingToNeeds(req.body)} /*this if-else is done to make it synchronous 
       so checking of vacate will be done and only after that other process will be done*/
     });
```

as you can see after calling **splitToStringAndConvertToInt()**
there is a Room.updateMany() query,so it is needed to call await before the query for proper synchronisation since node.js is asynchronous.
**so what i need to know is that Can i call await like that ,without returning promise?**

Comment: Yes, you _can_ use `await` on a non-promise, but if you're fully aware that it's not going to be a promise, then it's pretty pointless to do so and probably a waste of CPU cycles.

Comment: What i wanna do is to delay the next instruction to be executed until the current function returns value,so will the above code do it

Comment: yes, but the `await` isn't needed - each `splitStringAndConvertToInt` will run completely before the next one start, even without `await`

Comment: @AshwinJoshy If you are calling a synchronous function, then it will block the thread until it finishes executing and returns. You don't have to do anything special to wait for it, and you don't need `async` for that.

Comment: by the way, the code you presented won't run ... since `await` only works in `async` functions, and yours isn't - so, this is obviously not actual code that you are using - and, ironically you **don't** await in the one place that may actually be an async function that returns a Promise

Comment: @JLRishe this is a node.js project,so i heard that ,in this everything runs asynchronously ,so what i am worried about is the Room.updateMany() query it will  automatically start without values if the function isnt complete

Comment: @AshwinJoshy you "heard" wrong - asynchronous code runs asynchronously, not ALL code ... like `let a=1; let b=2` doesn't run asynchronously

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks for the information,i actuallly am a noobie in this,also i had added the async to function

Comment: no need, unless you need to `await Room.updateMany` (assuming that returns a Promise of course)

Comment: oh, wait, `Room.updateMany` takes a node style callback `function (err, result) {}` ... so, you can't `await` that either - therefore, you don't need `async` at all

Comment: @JaromandaX ok then i'll remove all awaits

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the function should return promises, or the function itself using async-await, then you can use await for it, if not the await will be without meaning

but your function does not need to be promise or async-await because it doesn't need time to be done

Comment: Actually there are another functions in my code that takes a lot of time,can you please suggest the edit for function splitStringAndConvertToInt() so that i can return a promise at the end.I am a noobie in promises,

Comment: @AshwinJoshy - other functions in your code are irrelevant to the code block you've presented

Comment: @JaromandaX actually this is not the full code,i'll sumit full code

Comment: @AshwinJoshy - if the rest of the code is AFTER the code you presented, it STILL doesn't matter